# Как задать класс элементу списка при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Есть такой компонент, который отвечает за динамическое отображение списка. Как при клике задать активный класс элементу, по которому кликнули. У меня пока получается, что все `<li>` получают данный класс.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <li
      v-for="itemProxy in proxyCountry" :key="itemProxy.id"
      class="list-group-item"
      :class="{active: isActive}"
      @click="viewCurrentProxy(itemProxy.id)"
      >
        id-{{ itemProxy.id }}. host: {{itemProxy.host}}
      </li>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "listProxyTypeItem",
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getProxyList");
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["proxyCountry"])
  },
  methods: {    
    viewCurrentProxy(id, e) {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      this.$store.dispatch("setProxyInfo", id);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: "listProxyTypeItem",
  data () {
    return {
      proxyCountry: [{id: 1, host: 'host 1'}, {id: 2, host: 'host 2'}, {id: 3, host: 'host 3'}, {id: 4, host: 'host 4'}, {id: 5, host: 'host 5'}]
    };
  },
  methods: {    
    viewCurrentProxy(id, e) {
  var options = document.querySelectorAll("li"); 
  options.forEach(function(o){
   o.className = "";
  });
  e.target.className = e.target.className =="active"?"":"active";
      // this.$store.dispatch("setProxyInfo", itemProxy.id);
    }
  }

})
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

    <li
      v-for="itemProxy in proxyCountry" :key="itemProxy.id"
      class="list-group-item"
      
      @click="viewCurrentProxy(itemProxy.id, $event)"
      >
        id-{{ itemProxy.id }}. host: {{itemProxy.host}}
      </li>  


</div>
```

Comment: Роман, попробовал как вы написали - так же все блоки становятся активными.

Comment: Вы все равно меняете глобальную переменную `this.isActive` от которого у него в шаблоне зависят все элементы. А класс лучше переключать так: `el.classList.toggle('active')`

Comment: @shub1nk поправил

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько это не глобальная переменная, но уже не имеет значения.

Comment: Может глобальной и не стоит называть, я имел в виду глобальная в компоненте т. к. она доступна везде в шаблоне и компоненте. Также я откредактировал код, можете посмотреть как я сделал чтобы был активным максимум 1 элемент.

Comment: Еще заметил что автор не правильно использует атрибут класса на элементе, поправил код у себя. У вас кстати все классы `<li>` сбиваются, то есть `list-group-item` теряется

Comment: Сделал таким образом `viewCurrentProxy(itemProxy, e) {
      document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
      e.target.classList.toggle('active');
      this.$store.dispatch("setProxyInfo", itemProxy.id);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Вы использовали одну переменную на все элементы. У каждого элемента должно быть свое isActive, которое можно легко изменить при клике. В `viewCurrentProxy` передаете `itemProxy`(это объект, он передается по ссылке, то есть в параметре у нас точно такой же объект что и отображается) и меняете лично его свойство `isActive`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: "listProxyTypeItem",
  data () {
    return {
      proxyCountry: [{id: 1, host: 'host 1', isActive: false }, {id: 2, host: 'host 2', isActive: false }, {id: 3, host: 'host 3', isActive: false }, {id: 4, host: 'host 4', isActive: false }, {id: 5, host: 'host 5', isActive: false }]
    };
  },
  methods: {    
    viewCurrentProxy (itemProxy) {
      // две строчки ниже если надо чтобы активным был максимум 1 элемент
      // const active = this.proxyCountry.find(i => i.isActive)
      // active && (active.isActive = false)

      itemProxy.isActive = !itemProxy.isActive
      // this.$store.dispatch("setProxyInfo", itemProxy.id);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li
    v-for="itemProxy in proxyCountry" 
    :key="itemProxy.id"
    :class="{active: itemProxy.isActive, 'list-group-item': true}"
    @click="viewCurrentProxy(itemProxy)"
  >
      id-{{ itemProxy.id }}. host: {{itemProxy.host}}
    </li>  
</div>
```

Также обратите внимание, если нужно использовать класс не зависящий от пременной data, который нужен по умолчанию, то не нужно писать два раза class как в Вашем вопросе, нужно вот так: `:class="{active: itemProxy.isActive, 'list-group-item': true}"`

Comment: Илья, попробовал ваше решение item.Proxy.isActive меняет значение с false на true, только почему-то класс не добавляется и рендеринг компонента не происходит. Бывает правлю код, сохранюсь, вебпак обновит компоненты и пункт становится активным, сразу почему-то это не происходит, пока не пойму в чем причина может быть

Comment: Скорее всего так происходит, потому что `proxyCountry` является вычисляемым значением `computed`, а эти значения кэшируются и пока оно не поменяется компонент не обновляется. В верном ли я направлении мыслю?

Answer (score 0):

Не обратил внимание что данные у вас из хранилища. У Вас же isActive не нужно сохранять в бд?

Если Вам надо менять isActive во всем хранилище, то можно сделать так: использовать computed где Вы указали getter и менять состояние state который возвращает этот геттер(то есть у Вас `proxyCountry` должен возвращать модифицированную переменную из state, эту переменную и надо менять). По идее Ваш `dispatch("setProxyInfo", itemProxy.id)` и должен менять isActive, не знаю что он у Вас делает. Вы можете переделать `setProxyInfo` чтобы он принимал id и объект данных которые изменились: `dispatch("setProxyInfo", {id: itemProxy.id, changed: {itemProxy.isActive}})`. Дальше в этом действии делаете поиск исходя из id, извлекаете нужный элемент, применяете измененные данные через мутацию. Последний шаг могу описать более подробно, но может Вам этот вариант и не нужен.

Есть еще более простой вариант, хранилище при этом не затрагивается, но isActive будет меняться для `itemProxy`, нужно на этапе created скопировать из геттера в data:

```
created () {
  this.proxyCountryData = this.proxyCountry
}
```

И заменить у Вас в коде `proxyCountry` на `proxyCountryData`

Если Вам достаточно просто переключать класс, то можете так и оставить.

Comment: `isActive` никак не связано с хранилищем. Просто читал, как у элементов управлять классами, нашел такое решение, но оно все элементы списка делало активным. Так-то только для переключения класса и нужно. Просто думал может в Vue.js есть какие-то свои рекомендации в таких ситуациях. В любом случае благодарю за развернутый ответ